# Problems converting mat formular to python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hope you can help.

I am working with the fifa20 dataset, which have around 85 variables describing the players. There are 6 variables I want to work with: attack_finishing, skill_dribbling, power_long_shots, skill_ball_control, mentality_positioning, mentality_penalties.

I have the following simple formular, which describes a players values for those variables:

attack_finishing: 70
skill_dribbling: 65
power_long_shots: 74
skill_ball_control: 67
mentality_positioning: 80
mentality_penalties: 70

Into the simpe formular: 
G_Score = (0.25 * 70) + (0.15 * 65) + (0.1 * 74) + (0.2 * 67) + (0.1 * 80) + (0.2 * 70)
G_Score = 65.05

My intention is to build a function, where I can call the function with a name from the dataset, and it will give me the G_Score of that player, based on the players values in the variables described above.

I tried with this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
fifa20 = pd.read_csv('players_20.csv', delimiter=',')

def Gscore(long_name): --> create the function, which takes the name of the player(long_name)
    for i in fifa20(attacking_finishing, skill_dribbling, power_long_shots, skill_ball_control, mentality_positioning, mentality_penaltites): --> the variables the function should take in fifa20 dataset
    i = (0.25 * 'attacking_finishing') + (0.15 * 'skill_dribbling') + (0.1 * 'power_long_shots') + (0.2 * 'skill_ball_control') + (0.1 * 'mentality_positioning') + (0.2 * 'mentality_penalties') --> try to put the formular in here
retrun (i) --> return the sum

Gscore('Alan Pulido') --> me calling trying to call the function, with a player name
```

I dont get a mistake from the function, but when I try to call I get this:

```
NameError: name 'attacking_finishing' is not defined
```

I now know, that there are quite some mistakes.

The format of the dataset would looks like this

Thank you!

---

Comment: Honestly the whole function `Gscore` makes no sense. It never uses the `long_name` parameter, all of the arguments to `fifa20()` are undefined, it immediately reassigns `i`, and multiplying a string by a float is invalid. Plus the indenting is wrong and `return` is misspelled. You've fundamentally misunderstood something, but I'm not sure what. Voting to close as "too broad" since there are too many things wrong. Please make a [mre].

Comment: It's gonna be hard to help without knowing the format of the fifa20 dataset.

Comment: Take a look at tutorials, do not try to make a function at the begining, proceed step by step, this might help : https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-read-csv

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for the reply - I edited my question, where I tried to explain it more in deep, and put comments into my code. I hope this clarified it a bit more - Thank you for the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to provide the solution to your problem, I'm rather going to help you get through your problem :

First of all, if you want to put comments in a python code, use : `#`

```
# this is a comment
```

So, your first 2 lines looks right:

```
import pandas as pd 
fifa20 = pd.read_csv('players_20.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Then you define your function :

```
def Gscore(long_name):
```

is 'long_name' the name of the column where the name is stored in the .csv ?
Anyway, you choose to pass this parameter to your function but you are not doing anything with it in your function.

The computer is dumb, it only does what you tell him to do (but he does it very fast).

If we write down in english what you are trying to achieve:

- You want to search in your dataset on which line the player name appears
- Then you want to apply your formula to the datas found on the line in which you found your player
- you want to return this value

so, to search in a dataset by column you would use :

```
for column in fifa20:
```

But here we want to check row by row, I didn't know how to do it so I just googled it and found we can use :

```
for index, row in fifa20.iterrows():
```

The content of the row being read is stored in the variable row, so if we are looking for the name of the player and if the name is stored in the 'long_name' column, we can check if we found the player we were looking for :

```
if row['long_name'] == long_name:
```

Then we can calculate the gscore of the player :

```
score = row['attacking_finishing'] * 0.15 + ...
```

If the datas are stored and parsed as strings and not as numbers, you might want to cast your values to float before multiplying them :

```
score = float(row['attacking_finishing']) * 0.15 + ...
```

then you can return your result :

```
return score
```

The important thing here is the fact we wrote down in english what we wanted to do, then we cut these tasks to small actions and last when translate it to any language we want.

Your problem here is not with python, it's with the description and the definition of what you are trying to do.

Do not hesitate to comment this answer, I'll improve it if you need additionnal help.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it and got it to work. Sorry for the late reply to your answer. Thanks again! :)